# Heroku Application Error after "build successful"

Tags: node.js, heroku

This is my first attempt in heroku deployment so I get Application error even though building is succesfull, it is mern app i am trying to deploy on heroku and it also works smoothly in local server.Here is logs from heroku site

```
2020-10-16T11:00:59.763981+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2020-10-16T11:00:59.763982+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the react-boiler-plate@1.0.0 start script.
2020-10-16T11:00:59.763983+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-10-16T11:00:59.794213+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-16T11:00:59.794215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-10-16T11:00:59.794215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-10-16T11_00_59_764Z-debug.log
2020-10-16T11:00:59.897369+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-16T11:00:59.964492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-16T11:11:55.766235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=travelagencya.herokuapp.com request_id=b7e97425-227f-445c-8fb9-70b4f9a2e678 fwd="88.231.62.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-10-16T11:11:59.001442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=travelagencya.herokuapp.com request_id=ba074c51-105a-4bff-b1fd-c428ee6d5dc6 fwd="88.231.62.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I searched through all day ,did mongodb connection which i thought what problem was at first.I can give further info , Also when i log in npm it is more elobarate ;

```
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745134+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745135+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745135+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745136+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745136+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './prod'
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745136+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745136+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/config/key.js
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745137+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/index.js
2020-10-16T10:34:01.745137+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-boiler-plate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react boiler plate",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engine": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "backend": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "frontend": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend\" \"npm run start --prefix client\""
  },
  "author": "Tolima",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.3",
    "supports-color": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: add package.json, heroku-postbuild tag details, and your folder and files structure

Comment: Oh sorry , package.json added